# How to populate table in MySql + Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to create a live search using NodeJS Angular and MySql. I found a tutorial and everything is clear for me except how to populate the database. I found only code for loading content from database.

```
app.get('/load',function(req,res){
    console.log("<== We are going to load data from Table ==>");
    connection.query("select * from cfg_demos",function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err) throw err;      
        console.log("<== Data is been loaded. ==>");
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));  
        console.log("<== Data is been sent to Client. ==>");                
    });

});
```

So how to find this `cfg_demos`?

There is another file:

```
app.controller('main_control',function($scope,$http){
            load_demos();
            function load_demos(){

                    $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
                            $scope.loaded_demos=data;
                        })

                }

    });
```

But it's also for extracting data from database and putting it to html page.

Files are [here](https://github.com/codeforgeek/live-ajax-search-angular). And the demo is [here](http://demo.codeforgeek.com/). It isn't an advertisement of course, I'm trying to understand how values from the last webpage appeared and how to populate the table.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you want to hit the database for each word entered in the search box?

Comment: @Shubh what do you mean by hit? I need to create a live search, google is ggod example. And search through database, which contains elements (i.e. 5000)